# How do you keep your motivation and enthusiasm for a never ending project?

Tags: motivation, persistence

At the beginning of a project I tend to finish tasks quickly. However, after a while I start getting bored doing the same thing over and over again. It feels like I am stagnant.

How do you keep enthusiasm running for a never ending project?

Comment: Exactly how i feel. Great Question, i hope someone here can give some advice.

Comment: This is known as a [death march](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(project_management)).  Give [Death March (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Death-March-2nd-Edward-Yourdon/dp/013143635X/) by Edward Yourdon (though I'd point out it may not be encouraging).

Comment: If there is no end, then by definition it isn't a project

Comment: The duplicate is not even close to the asked question. There's quite a difference between working on an "overwhelming" project and one that you work on for years but most certainly isn't overwhelming. Successful projects tend to result in the OPs dilemma, if your definition of successful is people actually using your project and wanting more of it. Overwhelming projects can happen at any phase.

Comment: @vin:My recommendation is to create tools. There's always something that can be better accomplished via automation. When creating the tools, use different languages, different design techniques, other tools etc. In other words, figure out how to expand your skillset while still "technically" doing project work.

Comment: @Dunk I feel this was a poor close reason, you are right they are not the same question nor do the answers make sense to the OP's question.  I do however feel this falls in the category of Primarily Opinion Based.  If you can think of a way to improve the question to where there is a more objectively answerable component to it then reflag and we can consider reopening.

Comment: If you're doing the same thing over and over, make a script that does the thing.